# Can not open connection to localhost database VS2013

Tags: c#, sql, connection, visual-studio-2013

I installed vs2013 today togheter with the mysql package for providing acces to mysql commands and references. Everything installed fine, but every time i try to open a connection, it says error 40.

I double checked everything but somehow, it can't connect. I also have wamp running and i can get a connection trough the wizard way in vs2013 (add database connection), but with coding, it doesn't work :(

here's my code:

```
SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=c#practicum;Uid=test;Pwd=test;Connection Timeout=5");
try
{
    Connection.Open();
    Connection.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("gelukt!");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("niet gelukt!");
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [MySqlConnector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.2.html) to work with MySql in C#.

Comment: I have installed it with the complete package as being said in the description above the page you linked :), and when i try to install it, it says that a later version is installed

Comment: @user3197307 he's referring to your C# code snippet: you are using `SqlConnection` which is for SQL Server connections only.

Comment: thanks! i saw that i was using system.data.sqlclient instead of your solution :D thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to get around this:

1. Installed VS2013, with update 2.
   Still had connectivity issue and was getting Access Violation Exception .

   Found following [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2915689)

   Accordingly installed [.Net Framework 4.5.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42642) and this resolved the issue.

   I am now able to make a connection to SQL Server.
2. Another work around could be to change your configuration from Any CPU to your OS specific architecture, I tried and this one worked on stand alone application, but didn't work on my project because there were specific components that were interfering and causing other functionality to blow up.
3. Revert to VS2012 and uninstalled .Net Framework 4.5.1.